# Understanding $ee\to h \to ff$ process

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

can anyone tell me where to find a good reference that talks about $$e^+ e^-\rightarrow H \rightarrow f\bar{f}$$ where this describes an electron-positron annihilation into a Higgs that in term produces heavy leptons.

Any reference that explains this process thoroughly will do it. I have searched many books on weak interactions but none of which handled it except one book "Gauge theories of the Strong, Weak, and Electromangnetic Interactions" that only gave a fast glimpse about it but I couldn't understand it from there.

Comment: You could look for lepton-lepton decay channel of higgs

Comment: lepton-lepton decay? leptons are being formed here. @Major_Tom

Comment: Higgs Decay of two tau leptons

Comment: If you have seen that some place or some book please let me know because google doesn't seem to precise in picking those. @Major_Tom

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for precisely but one of the articles [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5041)

Comment: I am more looking into a theoretical by-the-book explanation for this where cross section of the process is explained and all those stuff. Do you have any idea? @Major_Tom

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the cross section for that process from the Feynman rules? If so, what other information do you want? If not, is your question, how do I calculate this cross section?

Comment: I don't think you can find the exact same process  but you can find something similar in quantum field theory books if you are familiar with it.

Comment: What are you familiar with? What is your level of training in physics? If you want *all* the details, you might need to do a lot of work!

Comment: I am a bit familiar with Feynman rules and I have calculated one cross section before this but it was way easy and straight forward. Can you suggest a book that discusses this not necessarily with all the details but guidance throughout of which would be nice and I can fill the mathematical gaps? @innisfree

Comment: Any introduction to QFT. I think you're more likely to get a good answer if you make your current level of physics clearer. If you've calculated cross sections, why is this one tricky? and why can't you find books/resources about QFT yourself?

Comment: I calculated with guidance a single way process like $$ (...) \rightarrow (...)$$ and not a double way process like $$ (..) \rightarrow (...) \rightarrow (...)$$ and because of my unfamiliarity with this very subject I can't see how to hop from my previous experience to this. And I have searched QFT books of course but couldn't find this double process starting from annihilation of $e^ e^-$ to $Higgs$ to massive leptons. But if you are so sure that i will find this kind of rocess i will try to search again  @innisfree

Comment: This sort of calculation appears in any introduction to QFT book.

Comment: I have searched almost every book out there from Mandl to Ryder to Zee to Zuber to Schroeder. I got nothing. @innisfree

Comment: @beyondtheory:If you're familiar with the usual $e^+e^- \to Z \to f\bar{f}$, the similar process $e^+e^- \to H \to f\bar{f}$ is simpler since you just have to use a propagator for a scalar boson (the Higgs). A side remark: this is not the process you'd use to find the Higgs at $e^+ e^-$ colliders.

Comment: No I am not familiar with that process, would you mind telling me where I can get familiar with it? I would sincerely appreciate that. @Paganini

Comment: Have a look to general books like Halzen & Martin, Griffiths etc...

Comment: @Paganini Thank you. One more question, why did you consider the case at hand easier than the one with Z? Here you have to use a propagator and there also.

Comment: because, a scalar (spin 0 like the Higgs boson) doesn't carry any spin. The propagator does not depend on the Minkowski indices (no $g^{\mu\nu}$, no $\gamma^\mu$ and stuff like this).